# $\int^\infty_0 e^{-\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)\,dx = \frac{B}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ Laplace

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

$$
\int^\infty_0 \! e^{-\alpha x} \sin(\beta x)\,dx = \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}
$$

Can someone start this for me? I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hint: to get the antiderivative you can integrate by parts twice. (Alternately you can do this with complex exponentials.)

Comment: @Ian, I think another nice technique will be using the differentiation under integration technique.

Comment: This is a basic integral and a common example for integration by parts. If this is a duplicate, it should be closed as such and perhaps merged. Otherwise, I would hate to see it removed from the site simply because the OP has not provided context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest (or at least most economic) way to solve this is using the fact that $\sin(\beta x)=\Im[{e^{i\beta x}}]$:

$$
I=\Im\left[\int_0^{\infty}{e^{i\beta x- ax}}\right]=-\Im\left[\frac{1}{i\beta-a}\right]=\frac{\beta}{\beta^2+a^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to integrate by parts twice
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=-\frac1\alpha\int_0^\infty\sin(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-\alpha x}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac\beta\alpha\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=-\frac\beta{\alpha^2}\int_0^\infty\cos(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-\alpha x}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac\beta{\alpha^2}-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\[3pt]
&=\frac\beta{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: $e^{-\alpha x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac1\alpha\,\mathrm{d}e^{-\alpha x}$
$(3)$: integrate by parts
$(4)$: $e^{-\alpha x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac1\alpha\,\mathrm{d}e^{-\alpha x}$
$(5)$: integrate by parts
$(6)$: add $\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ times $(1)$ to $\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ times $(5)$